# How do I marshal a structure containing a array of int of unknown size?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have a c-structure that I want to return from a c-function to c# and that structure contains an array of int and a length. So basically

```
struct MyStruct
{
int *arr;
int size;
}
```

How should I allocate the arr in c to ensure that it can be freed in c#. And how do I decorate the corresponding structure in c# to make the marshalling possible?

Comment: To interop wtih C#, are you using C, C++, C++/CLI, C++/CX, C++ with WRL, or C++/WinRT?  Are you using .NET or Mono?  Are you on Windows or Macintosh or Linux?

Comment: Im working in C# and the library Im calling is C++, but I only call C-style functions. I use visual studio and .NET standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
You should allocate and free memory by same runtime library.

Comment: You can allocate memory in C code, use it in C#, AND free memory in C code (by calling user function).

Comment: Thanks, then I guess I dont need to search further. I had hoped that there should be something like SizeParamIndex for structs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeparamindex?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @AndersG What makes you think that SizeParamIndex doesn't work for structs?

Comment: Is it possible to use that for structs? How?